# PHP - Insert new column to CSV in between existing data

Tags: php, arrays, csv, sorting

I have details.csv with following content:

```
name,phone,address
john,123,abc
suse,134,bca
```

I want to insert empty new columns so it will become:

```
name,phone,city,postcode,address
john,123,"","",abc
suse,134,"","",bca
```

or become this (whichever is easier)

```
name,phone,city,postcode,address
john,123,city,postcode,abc
suse,134,city,postcode,bca
```

I did

```
<?php
$filename = 'details.csv';
$the_big_array = [];

if (($h = fopen("{$filename}", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
  while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
  {
  $data[] = 'city';
  $data[] = 'postcode';

    $the_big_array[] = $data;
  }

  fclose($h);
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($the_big_array);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

But I got this instead:

```
name,phone,address,city,postcode
john,123,abc,city,postcode
suse,134,bca,city,postcode
```

Help please..

Comment: Well, think it through...for a start, which bit of the code above do you think would be doing the adding of blank spaces??

Comment: I have no idea how to add blank spaces. Hence the question :)
However I figured out that I can replace the contents into blanks, after I successfully insert columns. 2 times work. But if there's no other way, then it's fine. Thanks.

Comment: Well something like `$data[] = '';`?? A blank space is just an empty string. Then start to think about the ordering of the columns. Bit the answer below may be a neater approach overall.

Comment: Yes the one below works well and $data[] = ''; at the beginning also good idea. I can then just workout on the 1st array (the header) instead of replacing. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_splice()`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

```
if (($h = fopen("{$filename}", "r")) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        array_splice($data, 2, 0, ['city', 'postcode']);

        $the_big_array[] = $data;
    }

    fclose($h);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works as per my request. Now I have another question.
Is it possible to put in different columns? eg. - john,city,123,postcode,abc -

Comment: @Pekzz you have to use two `array_splice()`